# Updating object in specified array also updates arrays containing objects of the same ID

Tags: php, arrays

I'm sorry if the title was confusing or poorly worded, I'm relatively new to programming terminology and couldn't think of a better description.

Here is a basic structure of the script, with irrelevant functions/variables removed:

```
class User {

    public $username;
    public $binders;

    function __construct($username, $binders) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->binders = $binders;
    }
}
```

The variable `$binders` is an array of `Binder` objects:

```
class Binder {

    public $name;
    public $contents;

    function __construct($name, $contents = array()) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->contents = $contents;
    }
}
```

The variable `$contents` is an array of `Card` objects:

```
class Card {

    public $id;
    public $quantity;

    function __construct($id, $quantity = 0) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }

}
```

So a simple structure could be:

```
$users = array(
    'TestName' => new User('TestName', array(
        'BinderName1' => new Binder('BinderName1', array(
            'CardID_1' => new Card('1', '20'),
            'CardID_3' => new Card('3', '10'),
        ),
        'BinderName2' => new Binder('BinderName2', array(
            'CardID_1' => new Card('1', '7')
        )
    )
);
```

I'm currently attempting to update the quantity of the card with `id` of 1 in the binder `BinderName1`, using the following code:

```
$users['TestName']->binders['BinderName1']->contents['CardID_1']->quantity = 5;
```

However, when I use `print_r($users)` after applying the change, the response shows that the quantity of CardID_1 updates in both `BinderName1` and `BinderName2`.  Am I applying the change incorrectly?

Edit: it appears as though this only occurs when I create a clone of an object, eg:

```
$card = $users['TestName']->binders['BinderName1']->contents['CardID_1'];
$cloneCard = clone $card;
array_push($users['TestName']->binders['BinderName1']->contents, $cloneCard);
```

Comment: I was curious, but not reproducible: http://3v4l.org/p28ma I did have to add some parentheses in the array definition though.

Comment: @AbraCadaver The link provided does not seem to be correct "Script loaded from database. Saved on 02/03/2015 10:48am". I have done more testing and noticed that this only occurs after I have inserted a clone into `Binder` array. I've added to my original post to clarify.

Comment: I changed the link.  Update the question with the code that causes the issue.